# Observing changes of an NSArray in a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, key-value-observing

I am using `KVO` to observe an array's changes, the array will be changed in a cell which is in a `tableViewController`'s `tableView`. And I have assign the array which is in the cell to a public `NSArray` property for other view controllers to use, their address are the same.

While I need to observer the value changes of the properties of the `tableViewController` from the `otherViewController`. I am able to observe other properties with `NSString` and other types, and I **have implemented** related array accessors for adding removing objects in the array in the custom cell class. **But** unable to get the notification of changes of the array.

I use `NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew | NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld` for options. I guess is the problem is I put the array in the cell caused `KVO` cannot reaches there?

*SDK Version: iOS 7.1*

Here is my view hierarchy of this part:

```
 tableViewController            
+-----------------------------+
| tableView                   |
|+----------+                 | 
||   cell   |                 |
||+--------+|        public   |
|||        ||        array    |
||| array  ||        property |
||| +----+ || assign +----+   |    (Observer)
||| |    |-++--------|    |<--+--[ otherViewController ]
||| +----+ ||   to   +----+   |
||+--------+|                 |
||          |                 |
|+----------+                 |
+-----------------------------+
```

#### Update

*For more clear, I add my implementation here*

In the `otherViewController`'s `- viewDidLoad` method:

```
[self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"self.tableViewController.theArray" options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew | NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld) context:nil];
```

In the `tableViewController`'s `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`:

```
self.theArray = cell.theArray
```

Comment: It can be some issue of how you access the items in the array `But what I didn’t know was that direct ivar manipulation doesn’t trigger KVO`.Check this post , hope it will help you http://qualitycoding.org/dot-notation-wins/

Comment: for KVO related, I using dot notation here. I am not sure using ivar will trigger KVO or not either, I can play with that :)

Comment: Your update is really weirded. Since tableview has many cells, this will cause you observe random array in cell.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you observe keypath "array" of cell like

```
    [cell addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"array" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew | NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld context:NULL];
```

Depend on https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVOCompliance.html

Automatic Change Notification only trigger on mutableArrayValueForKey: proxy.

If you want to trigger KVO on this implementation, you should implement array accessor as following:

```
- (void)addArrayObject:(id)object {
    NSMutableArray *notifiableArray = [self mutableArrayForKeyPath:@"array"];
    [notifiableArray addObject:object];
}
```

and remember removing old observer when cell is being reused.

Hope this can help you.

Comment: this is worth to try!! I will update the status after I have something :)

Answer (score 0):

You can manually send notification for the observed key

```
[self willChangeValueForKey:@"your key path"];
[array addObject:object];`
[self didChangeValueForKey:@"your key path"];
```